# Origen: Direct flow branching control

Tags: origen-sdk

I've been looking through the flow code for a way to more directly control the pass/fail branching on test nodes for 93k.  We could add additional hooks into the 93k output side of origen-testers, but then we risk breaking the platform agnosticism.

Instead, I believe that if we can more directly influence how the ATP data structure is built then the tester output drivers that already exist would handle it properly.  The ATP supports :on_pass and :on_fail keys already, but it appears to currently only support bins being placed into those blocks.

What I'd like to do would be able to write a flow like this:

```
func :test1, param1_key: param1_value, on_pass: do
    func :test2, param2_key: param2_value
end, on_fail: do
    func :test3, param3_key: param3_value
    bin 10
end
```

I realize that I can do this with flow control variables, but if there are a lot of tests that need this type of structure that leads to a lot of test ids and flow control variables.  Being able to directly say what tests are in the pass vs fail paths would greatly simplify the flow.  It also naturally leads to the ability to nest, for instance if test2 above needs a pass and fail path.

I'm still learning ruby, but I realize the above code throws compile errors.  I believe we can accomplish something like this with a little recursion in the flow builder and using lambdas:

```
func :test1, param1_key: param1_value, on_pass: ->{
    func :test2, param2_key: param2_value
}, on_fail: ->{
    func :test3, param3_key: param3_value
    bin 10
}
```

Is there already a way to more directly control or influence the internal ATP flow data structure?  If not, can we add something like what I have above to the enhancement request list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that opposed to this syntax suggestion, but this is how it should be coded using the currently available API:

```rb
func :test1, param1_key: param1_value, id: :t1

if_passed :t1 do
  func :test2, param2_key: param2_value
end

if_failed :t1 do
  func :test3, param3_key: param3_value
  bin 10
end
```

This fully supports nesting too:

```rb
func :test1, param1_key: param1_value, id: :t1

if_passed :t1 do
  func :test2, param2_key: param2_value, id: :t2

  if_failed :t2 do
    func :test4
  end
end

if_failed :t1 do
  func :test3, param3_key: param3_value
  bin 10
end
```

Adding support for blocks/lambdas being passed to `on_pass` and `on_fail` is maybe not quite as easy to implement as you think. e.g. it should map fairly directly to V93K, but on Teradyne we would need to flatten it all out and generate flags since it does not provide a corresponding nestable IF structure.

I think this Origen source code is pretty readable and un-ambiguous, which is what we were striving for at that level. Ideally we hoped that the flow code might even be readable by non-technical stakeholders so that it could serve as documentation of the flow.

I think what you are really trying to address is the fact that this will currently generate flow control variables that don't really need to be there, but they will be gone soon.
The approach we are taking is to generate the internal low level implementation with meta data helpers like the flow variables in place, this makes it pretty easy to target to Teradyne which provides much less flow control power vs. V93K.

Then for 93K, or other platforms which provide similar C-like flow control APIs, the compiler will run some optimizations on the internal representation to get rid of redundant flag structures before final rendering.

Work on the next round of optimizations is already underway, keep an eye on this pull request - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/pull/52. I will add some additional test cases like the ones mentioned here to ensure that the unnecessary flags get optimized away.

If you follow the coding guidelines above it will generate a logically correct test program, then in a couple of weeks you can update to a new version of OrigenTesters and the output will get much prettier.

Comment: OrigenTesters 0.13.0 should fully optimize the case above to produce no redundant flow branches or variables vs. what would be expected.

Comment: @arkoh, please try 0.13.0 and accept this answer if it meets your needs. Thanks!